# SQL Server Windows Login - Same Name Different User (SID)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, active-directory

I'm having a problem with an windows login to sql 2008 r2 server.

A user was created in active directory lets call him "mydomain\jon.doe" and an windows login was created on the SQL server.

Because of an problem with exchange this AD account was deleted and a new one created still called "mydomain\jon.doe"

I ran the following to delete the old user from my sql server...

```
  EXECUTE('USE ' + @Database + ' IF EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.Schemas WHERE [name] = ''' + @FullyQualifiedUserName + ''') BEGIN DROP SCHEMA [' + @FullyQualifiedUserName + '] PRINT ''Deletion '' END')

  EXECUTE('USE ' + @Database + ' IF EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.Schemas WHERE [name] = ''' + @SimpleUserName + ''') BEGIN DROP SCHEMA [' + @SimpleUserName + '] PRINT ''Deletion '' END')

  EXECUTE('USE ' + @Database + ' IF EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = ''' + @FullyQualifiedUserName + ''') BEGIN DROP USER [' + @FullyQualifiedUserName + '] PRINT ''Deletion '' END')

  EXECUTE('USE ' + @Database + ' IF EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = ''' + @SimpleUserName + ''') BEGIN DROP USER [' + @SimpleUserName + '] PRINT ''Deletion '' END')
```

However when I then re-add "mydomain\jon.doe" to the sql server it seems to have kept the old SID not the SID of the new AD Account?

I've tried this so far... but no luck

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL')
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround might be to create a group in Active Directory that only contains "mydomain\jon.doe", and add a SQL login for this group.

Comment: This is the correct preventative measure for this and many other reasons.  If you use group memberships for all AD access, then this kind of snafu can be avoided.  However, it won't clear the bad SID that is there because it seems that Mr. NoseBag may have deleted the DB users but not the login itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows the Database user drop, but did you drop the LOGIN from the server?

```
[your user drops]
Use master 
go
DROP LOGIN [mydomain\jon.doe];
```

If not, then the SQL Server is still linking to the AD User with the old SID.

If you run

```
xp_logininfo 'mydomain\jon.doe'
```

...do you get error 0x534?  If so then you definitely need to do this:

1. Drop the user as a database user from all databases on the server;
2. Drop the login;
3. Re-add the login;
4. Re-add the user.

This will clear the old SID from SQL Server and you will be working properly again.